# How to clear GPU memory after training each fold

Tags: tensorflow, multiprocessing, multi-gpu

I am getting an error after a few folds of training is done..
The error states:
Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 16.15GiB (rounded to 17338417152)requested by op _EagerConst
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation.

I checked the gpu allocation using nvidia-smi

It shows 1st GPU is using 33/48 GB
The other 3 are using 13/48 GB

After a few folds, it shows GPU out of memory error.
I tried the workaround **    tf.keras.backend.clear_session() but that doesn't help

#other imports
.
.

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
for device in physical_devices:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device, True)

strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))
..
model code
..
#k fold training loop 
num_folds = 10
kfold = KFold(n_splits=num_folds, shuffle=True)
fold = 0
for train, val in kfold.split(X_train, y_train_one_hot):
    with strategy.scope():
        model = create_model()

    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(f'classifier_with_attention_model.{fold + 1}.h5', save_best_only=True)
    history = model.fit(X_train[train], y_train_one_hot[train], epochs=100, batch_size=64,
                        validation_data=(X_train[val], y_train_one_hot[val]), callbacks=[checkpoint])
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    scores = model.evaluate(X_train[val], y_train_one_hot[val])
    fold += 1
    print(f"Fold: {fold}, Loss: {scores[0]}, Accuracy: {scores[1]}")
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
    history_list.append(history)
.
```

.
.
after a few folds I am getting the error as gpu ran out of memory

Answer (score 0):

By default, Tensorflow will try to allocate all available GPU memory, which can lead to issues if other processes require GPU memory, that is what is happening in your scenario. So you must configure memory usage which involves a session with a parameter set.

1. Import required libraries (i use keras).

> ```
> import tensorflow as tf
> from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
> ```

2. Configure GPU Memory Usage

> ```
> config = tf.ConfigProto() config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True sess
> = tf.Session(config=config) set_session(sess)
> ```

3. Execute the model per your needs
4. Clear GPU Memory

> ```
> sess.close()
> tf.reset_default_graph()
> ```